# Gmail Contact Remove From other Mobile

Tags: contacts, gmail

I once had to log in my Google account on my friend's phone and I  delete my account on his phone. Is there any way for me to remotely delete my Contacts on my friend's devices?

Answer (score 0):

You can log in to Google and navigate to https://myaccount.google.com/security#activity and remove that device.